# Lost ENS name due to auction deadlock?

Tags: ens, auctions

I started an ENS auction on ropsten, but I forgot to bid.

Now the auction date has passed. The name is listed as `not available`:

```
 > ethRegistrar.entries(web3.sha3('name'))[0]
 1
```

The owner, however, seems to be nobody:

```
 > deedContract.at(ethRegistrar.entries(web3.sha3('name'))[1]).owner();
 "0x"
```

The name is obscure, so I think most likely there was no bids at all as it expired. Either that, or the other bidder(s) forgot to reveal bids before the end.

I tried to finalize it, and got some transaction hash. But it doesn't change anything.

Is the name now lost forever?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the name now lost forever?

Testnets are only transient. They can be withdrawn - or attacked - at any time, so even if the name isn't lost now, it would have been (will be) at some indefinite time in the future.

A couple of further ideas:

- I haven't kept up with the state of Ropsten after the spam attack earlier in the month, but it's possible that it's still in a bad way. (Someone can correct me on that.)
- With the [postponement of the official ENS launch](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/5zg1u3/ens_launch_officially_postponed_well_back_off/) and discovery of bugs [[1](https://github.com/ethereum/ens/pull/48), [2]](https://github.com/ethereum/ens/issues/49) in the contract code, it's probably wise to give ENS some breathing space until things are back up and running.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I somehow read this totally wrong, and had gotten the impression they would persist also *after* the transition. That doesn't make too much sense, though, now that I think of it. Thanks.